# How to extract the text from (bs4.element.Tag)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, jupyter, alfresco-webscripts

How can I extract the "Data Engineer" text from

```html
<a class="jobTitle-link" href="/job/Data-Engineer/861664201/">Data Engineer</a>
```

Sample Code should be fine.

Comment: Please accept an answer if your problem has been fixed, or otherwise offer clarification if you were looking for a different one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".jobTitle-link").innerText;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<a class="jobTitle-link" href="/job/Data-Engineer/861664201/">Data Engineer</a>
```